# Peer Upgrade command not running

Tags: hyperledger, chaincode

I am trying to build a supply chain blockchain, using a reference from github. I have modified the contents of the chaincode and trying to update the chaincode using the command:

```
peer upgrade -name of the file
```

However after I am getting a an error:

```
Command 'peer' not found, did you mean:

command 'pee' from deb moreutils
command 'peet' from deb pipexec
command 'pear' from deb php-pear
command 'seer' from deb seer
command 'beer' from deb gerstensaft

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Please someone help

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "peer upgrade" command. I suggest you review the official docs that includes step by step on how to perform several tasks. A chincode upgrade it's almost identical to a chaincode deployment as detailed here:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/fa/latest/deploy_chaincode.html